# OpenCart sort shipping by cost. Is json changing the sorting of my array?

Tags: php, html, arrays, json, opencart

I am trying to change the sorting of shipping prices to ASC in opencart "Estimate Shipping & Taxes" section of the cart.

I changed the sort of the array in php using "uasort", and everything looks good, but when the json loop prints it out in the tpl, its in the wrong order again.

/catalog/controller/total/shipping.php

When printing the php array it is in the right order:

```
Array
(
    [free] => Array
    (
        [title] => Free Shipping
        [quote] => Array
            (
                [free] => Array
                    (
                        [code] => free.free
                        [title] => Free Shipping
                        [cost] => 0
                        [tax_class_id] => 0
                        [text] => $0.00
                    )

            )

        [sort_order] => 1
        [error] => 
    )

    [usps] => Array
    (
        [title] => United States Postal Service
        [quote] => Array
            (
                [00] => Array
                    (
                        [code] => usps.00
                        [title] => First-Class Mail Parcel
                        [cost] => 4.54
                        [tax_class_id] => 0
                        [text] => $4.54
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [code] => usps.4
                        [title] => USPS Retail Ground
                        [cost] => 7.29
                        [tax_class_id] => 0
                        [text] => $7.29
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [code] => usps.1
                        [title] => Priority Mail 2-Day
                        [cost] => 7.3
                        [tax_class_id] => 0
                        [text] => $7.30
                    )

            )

        [sort_order] => 2
        [error] => 
    )

)
```

Prints out correctly in json

```
{"shipping_method":{"free":{"title":"Free Shipping","quote":{"free":{"code":"free.free","title":"Free Shipping","cost":0,"tax_class_id":0,"text":"$0.00"}},"sort_order":"3","error":false},"usps":{"title":"United States Postal Service","quote":{"00":{"code":"usps.00","title":"First-Class Mail Parcel","cost":4.54,"tax_class_id":"0","text":"$4.54"},"4":{"code":"usps.4","title":"USPS Retail Ground","cost":7.29,"tax_class_id":"0","text":"$7.29"},"1":{"code":"usps.1","title":"Priority Mail 2-Day","cost":7.3,"tax_class_id":"0","text":"$7.30"}},"sort_order":"2","error":false}}}
```

However end result shows them in the original order

/catalog/view/theme/default/template/total/shipping.tpl

```
Please select the preferred shipping method to use on this order.

Free Shipping
Free Shipping - $0.00

United States Postal Service
Priority Mail 2-Day - $7.30
USPS Retail Ground - $7.29
First-Class Mail Parcel - $4.54
```

Maybe I am just tired but seems I am missing something obvious.
What am I doing wrong.

The original files can be viewed here...
https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/catalog/controller/total/shipping.php
https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/catalog/view/theme/default/template/total/shipping.tpl

Comment: It's because your array has weird array keys. The one with the key '1' will be the 1st, '4' will be the 2nd, and '00' is handled as a string, so it will be the last one. I'd recommend running your "quote" array through `array_values()` first.

Comment: @TiborB. Fresh eyes and its obvious. Thanks!

Comment: Create answer and I will check it, exact line was "$quote['quote'] = array_values($quote['quote']);" above "$quote_data[$result['code']] = array(" in "/catalog/controller/total/shipping.php"

Comment: Spoke too soon, those weird keys are used in the form, so changing them breaks it. Back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it did not work was because it also stores the array in the session and the form field  must match the original shipment type key (i.e. "usps.00" with [00]).

```
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="usps.00">
```

Im just guessing though; I didnt look very thorough.

Because I do not know know to resort multidimensional arrays in json I duplicated the "$quote_data" array in "/catalog/controller/total/shipping.php", sorting cost with usaort() then using array_values(), so the original keys are stored in the session and json get the modified keys.

If you want to use my hacky method here it is...

REPLACE

```
<?php
// START EDIT - FUNCTION TO RESORT BY PRICE/COST
function sortbycost ($a, $b) {
    return $a['cost'] > $b['cost'];
}
//END EDIT
class ControllerTotalShipping extends Controller {
```

REPLACE

```
                if ($quote) {

                    // START EDIT - FUNCTION TO SORT BY QUOTE (PRICE/COST)
                    uasort($quote['quote'], 'sortbycost');

                    // ADDED SECOND ARRAY (DUPLICATE ARRAY TO BE STORED IN SESSION)
                    $quote_data2[$result['code']] = array(
                        'title'      => $quote['title'],
                        'quote'      => $quote['quote'],
                        'sort_order' => $quote['sort_order'],
                        'error'      => $quote['error']
                    );

                    // REPLACE KEYS FOR JS LOOP
                    $quote['quote'] = array_values($quote['quote']);
                    // END EDIT

                    $quote_data[$result['code']] = array(
                        'title'      => $quote['title'],
                        'quote'      => $quote['quote'],
                        'sort_order' => $quote['sort_order'],
                        'error'      => $quote['error']
                    );
                }
```

REPLACE

```
        //$this->session->data['shipping_methods'] = $quote_data; //  ORIGINAL
        $this->session->data['shipping_methods'] = $quote_data2; // EDIT - KEEP DUPLICATE ARRAY WITH THE ORIGINAL KEYS IN SESSION
```

REPLACE

```
            //$json['shipping_method'] = $this->session->data['shipping_methods']; // ORIGINAL
            $json['shipping_method'] = $quote_data; // EDIT - USE THE NEW KEYS
```

It would probably be better to just re-sort the data in the javascript of the template file, but like I said, I do not know how to do that.